# Two Timing (Multiple Time Scales) with Coupled IVPs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

**Question:** Find the leading-order approximation for times of order $\epsilon^{-1}$ to $$\ddot{x} + x = y,~~\dot{y} = \epsilon(xy - 2y^2),~~x(0) = 1,~~\dot{x}(0) = 0,~~y(0)=1.$$

**My approach:** Let the fast time scale of oscillation be $\tau = t$ and the slow time scale of amplitude drift be $T = \epsilon t$. Further, $$x(t;\epsilon) = X(\tau, T; \epsilon) = X_0(\tau, T) + \epsilon X_1(\tau, T) + O(\epsilon^2),$$ $$y(t;\epsilon) = Y(\tau, T; \epsilon) = Y_0(\tau, T) + \epsilon Y_1(\tau, T) + O(\epsilon^2).$$

At $O(1)$, the set of PDEs is:
$$(X_0)_{\tau\tau} + X_0 = Y_0,~\frac{\partial Y_0}{\partial \tau} = 0,$$ subject to the initial conditions $X_0(0,0) = 1$, $\frac{\partial X_0}{\partial \tau}(0,0) = 0,~Y_0(0,0) = 1$. Solving the above system leads us to $$Y_0(\tau, T) = f(T),~X_0(\tau, T) = A(T)e^{i\tau} + A^*(T)e^{-i\tau} + f(T) = \left[Ae^{i\tau} + cc\right] + f(T)$$ with $f(0) = 1$ and $A(0) = 0$ (***which is weird and leads to problems***).

At $O(\epsilon)$, the set of PDEs is:
$$(Y_1)_{\tau} = -(Y_0)_T + X_0Y_0 - 2Y_0^2,$$ $$\frac{\partial^2 X_1}{\partial \tau^2} + X_1 = -2\frac{\partial^2 X_0}{\partial\tau \partial T} + Y_1,$$
subject to the initial condition $Y_1(0,0) = 0$ (note that we do not require the initial conditions on $X_1$ to solve the problem). Solving the first PDE leads us to $$Y_1(\tau, T) = -f_T\tau + fA\left[-ie^{i\tau} + cc\right] - f^2\tau + g(T),$$ where $g(0) = 0$. Therefore, $$\frac{\partial^2 X_1}{\partial \tau^2} + X_1 = \left[e^{i\tau}(-2iA_T-fAi) + cc\right] + \tau\left[-f_{T} -f^2\right] + (\text{non-secular terms}).$$

We need to set the first two terms on the right-hand side of the last PDE to $0$ to avoid secular behavior. Thus, we must have $$\frac{df}{dT} + f^2 = 0,$$ subject to $f(0) =1$, which implies $$f(T) = \frac{1}{T+1}.$$ Further, assuming $A(T) = R(T)e^{i\theta(T)}$, we must also have (*amplitude equation*):
$$A_T + \frac{1}{2}fA = R_T + iR\theta_T + \frac{1}{2}fR = 0.$$ Equating the real and imaginary parts, we arrive at the following ODEs:
$$\frac{dR}{dT}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{R}{T+1} = 0,~R\frac{d\theta}{dT} = 0,$$
subject to $R(0) = 0$ and $\theta(0)$ can be any angle (***problem 1***).

Solving the ODE on $R$ gives us $R(T) \equiv 0$ (***problem 2***). This implies, in this case, we would not be able to solve the ODE on $\theta$ (***problem 3***).

I might be wrong, but I feel that either $x(0) = 0$ or $y(0) = 0$; both cannot be equal to $1$. It would be great if someone could confirm. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying out how this looks like numerically, integrate with $ϵ=0.05$ as example.

[image]

This looks like $x=y+ϵu$, $u(0)=0$, that is, in your expansion the $X_0$ component does not oscillate, the oscillation happens in $X_1$, so what you computed is actually correct, you just need to advance to the next step.

---

Alternatively transform first the system without series expansion. Eliminate $x$ using $y-x = -ϵu$ and $x-2y = -(y-ϵu)$, and in the derivative
$$
ϵ v \overset{Df.} = \dot x =\underbrace{-ϵy(y-ϵu)}_{=\dot y}  + ϵ\dot u
\\
\implies
\dot u = v + y(y-ϵu).
$$
Now insert into the first equation
$$
\dot v = \frac{1}{ϵ}\ddot x = \frac{1}{ϵ}(y-x)=-u ,~~v(0)=0
$$
and as already used, the second equation transforms to
$$
\dot y = - ϵy(y-ϵu)
$$
Plotting this system shows all components at the same scale

[image]

One could now switch to a systematic perturbation expansion, but let's go just one step further in the manual transformation. Set $w=v+y^2$, $w(0)=1$, then
\begin{align}
\dot u &= w - ϵyu\\
\dot w &= -u - 2ϵy^2(y-ϵu)\\
\dot y &= - ϵy(y-ϵu)
\end{align}
Thus with $z=u+iw$
$$
\dot z=-iz-ϵy(Re(z)+i2y(y-ϵRe(z))),\\ z(0)=i\implies z=ie^{-it}+O(ϵ)
$$

At level 0 this properly decouples as $u=\sin t$, $w=\cos t$, $y=1$. For a two-time-scales approach you would next introduce the slow variable $T=ϵt$ and equip the solution with slowly changing constants
$$
z_0(t,T)=A(T)e^{-it}+B(T)e^{it},  y_0(t,T)=C(T) \\
A(0)=i,~~B(0)=0,~~ C(0)=1.
$$
On the next level, with $z=z_0+ϵz_1+...$, etc.
\begin{alignat}{1}
\dot z_1 &= -iz_1 - C(T)Re(A(T)e^{-it}+B(T)e^{it})-i2C(T)^3&-A'(T)e^{-it}-B'(T)e^{-it}\\
\dot y_1 &= - C(T)^2 -C'(T)
\end{alignat}

The secular terms in the first equation are those that contain $e^{-it}$. To avoid resonances, set them to zero
$$
0=\frac{C(T)}2(A(T)+\overline{B(T)}+A'(T)
$$
The remaining equation gives
$$
\dot z_1+iz_1 = + \overline{A'(T)}e^{it} - 2iC(T)^3 - B'(T)e^{it} 
$$
It appears natural to demand $\overline{A'(T)} - B'(T) = 0$, giving $A(T)-\overline{B(T)}=i$ and using $C=-C'/C$ leading to
$$
A(T)=\frac i2(1+C(T)), \\ B(T)=\frac i2(1-C(T)).
$$
It remains to solve
$$
\dot z_1+iz_1=-2iC^3, ~~ z_1(0)=0,\\
z_1 = -2C^3 + 2C_1(T) e^{-it}, ~~~C_1(0)=1.
$$

So in reverse the steps are

```
i = 1j
T = eps*t
C = 1/(1+T); A = 0.5*i*(1+C); B = 0.5*i*(1-C)
z_0 = A*exp(-i*t) + B*exp(i*t) # = -C*sin(t) + i*cos(t)
z_1 = -2*C**3*(1-exp(-i*t))

u = z_0.real + eps*z_1.real # = -C*sin(t) + 2*eps*(cos(t)-C**3)
w = z_0.imag + eps*z_1.imag # = +cos(t) -2*eps*sin(t)
y = C
v = w - y**2
dx = eps*v
x = y + eps*u
```

giving the plot

[image]

This looks qualitatively correct, quantitatively only in the short term.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot! :)